# Issue accessing github repository

Tags: debian, git, https, github

For some reason my Debian Jesse server cannot access `github.com` at all, whether from `git clone` or even `links`.

I'm trying to

```
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
```

but get the following:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/certbot/certbot/':
Couldn't connect to server
```

I can browse to multiple other https sites using links, but for some reason github is giving me troubles.

I'm not sure what other information I can provide for you, but am glad to provide anything asked.

Comment: if your machine can't access `github.com` at all there's not much you can do other than wait (if github is the only service affected it's likely a temporary problem on your route).  you could attempt to connect through a proxy service if you need it now.

Comment: @quixotic If I navigate to `https://github.com/certbot/certbot` on another machine on my local network, everything's peachy.

Comment: can you navigate to `https://github.com` on the problem machine?  `http://github.com`?  if not, run `traceroute` on the problem machine and the working machine and compare the output.

Comment: see if wireshark gives any hints

Comment: I was able to resolve this, my `/etc/network/interfaces` was not correctly configured. I'm not sure how I was able to get to some sites but not others. I don't know if I should close this question or what.